# Angular how to handle diacritics like umlauts?

Tags: angular, diacritics

I have to import some values from a database with a lot of entries, so I can't change the names of the values inside. Now my problem is that there are some values like `tätigkeit` and I can't use it. Here a example:

```html
<div id="task">
  Tätigkeit:
  {{person.tätigkeit}}
 </div>
```

Now Angular shows me a error because of `tätigkeit`:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Lexer Error: Unexpected character [ä] at column 9 in expression [person.tätigkeit]'

How can I fix problems like that?

Answer (score 2):

If, as I assume, `person` is an object with a *key* (not a value) of `tätigkeit`, you can retrieve it as a string doing `person["tätigkeit"]`.

If you have an object `obj` with a key `example`, then `obj.example` and `obj["example"]` are equivalent, but Typescript does not support arbitrary unicode characters in the code, so you can't do `obj.tätigkeit`. The string way with `[]` will always work, however.

Comment: Thx for the answer! person["tätigkeit"] does not work. Tätigkeit is in this case a attribute from person. Similiar like person.age

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in the backend:

```js
public async Task<ActionResult> GetPersonens() {
    return Ok(await _context.Personens.Select(p => new {
        taetigkeit = p.Tätigkeit,
    }).ToListAsync());
}
```